# Android Room - can I store database in external storage

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to store the database in the external storage?

**Note:** I'm using the latest version of Room.

Comment: It is trivial that, you should not store database into external storage as it can breach security aspects easily.

Comment: @Wizard I need to do that because of my app users need, what's your option?

Comment: Any solution to this question? I'm also figuring out how to do it.